# process.nextTick: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: angular, sass

I have a angular project. Thus when I hit npm start I get the error:

```
> del-proj@0.0.0 build
> ng build

Node.js version v21.0.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
node:internal/event_target:1084
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
TypeError [Error]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at /home/user_name/project_path/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:104395:12
```

This is the project's dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.4",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
```

I deleted node_module folder, run npm i, then npm start and the error persists.

I hope someone would figure it out what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't support odd versions of Node and Node20 support hasn't landed yet.

You should downgrade to node 18/use `nvm` to set the node version to 18.

You can track the Node20 support on [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26114).

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me! Now I'm using node 18

Answer (score 0):

I have had a very similar error message when I didn't add my scss correctly.

I did come across this post regarding what causes the error

*SOLUTION:*

'Make sure you do not have trailing or dangling Saas operators like &. in your stylesheets

[Post where I found my problem/solution](https://thabo-ambrose.medium.com/typeerror-error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-column-3831bb15f395)